# VM Crashes on launching application/ JDK8+Jacoco

Tags: java-8, runtimeexception, jvm-crash, jacoco-maven-plugin

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\bin\java" -javaagent:C:\Users\test\.m2\repository\org\jacoco\org.jacoco.agent\0.6.4.201312101107\org.jacoco.agent-0.6.4.201312101107-runtime.jar

Getting:
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: $jacocoAccess

Comment: what version of `jacoco` are you using? seems like `0.6.4`... if so, you should upgrade to something bigger than `0.7.0`

Comment: Yes. Thanks @Eugene.0.7.6 worked.

Answer (score 0):

Worked with version:

`<maven-jacoco-plugin.version>0.7.6.201602180812</maven-jacoco-plugin.version>`